# having trouble validating email addresses in php

Tags: php, email-validation

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong here. Trying to validate an email address:

```
if (!preg_match("/^( [a-zA-Z0-9] )+( [a-zA-Z0-9\._-] )*@( [a-zA-Z0-9_-] )+( [a-zA-Z0-9\._-] +)+$/" , $emailREG)) {
```

Comment: I don't speak regex, so I can't be sure, but it looks like you're not allowing for the `+` character. If you're able to, please do. It irritates me when email validators, basically, don't.

Comment: Your first problem was trying to validate email with a regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36261/test-expand-my-email-regex/36277#36277

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using [FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL](http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp) instead:

```
<?php
    $email = "someone@exa mple.com";

    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
      echo "E-mail is not valid";
    }else{
      echo "E-mail is valid";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with filter_var with FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL. "somebody@example" will be validated as a valid email address because, well, it is a valid email address but may not be desirable.

You can also use the validate PEAR package.